# Is OpenSSL HMAC vulnerable to length extesion attacks when using MD5 as hash algorithm?

Tags: hmac, md5, length-extension

Given that a valid hash for a specific payload is known, would some C code like this be vulnerable to a length extension attack?

```
#include <openssl/hmac.h>
...
unsigned char *calculated_hash = HMAC(EVP_md5(), &key,sizeof(key) - 1, payload, payload_len, NULL, NULL);
...
    if(memcmp(calculated_hash, received_hash, 16) == 0){
        dprintf(client_fd, "Payload Valid\n");
        exit(0);
    } else {
        dprintf(client_fd, "Payload Invalid\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HMAC-MD5 is not vulnerable to length-extension attacks, period.

If that's what your code computes, then your code is not vulnerable to length-extension attacks.  That said:

1. Length-extension attacks are a part of the *protocol*, not an *implementation* of the protocol.  It doesn't matter whether you use OpenSSL or something else to implement the same protocol.

   You should have a concise description of your protocol and generate test vectors, *e.g.* with Python or Go, to confirm that your C code is computing the cryptography you intend in the protocol.  You should also have a clear statement in a design document of what your protocol accomplishes, without reference to the cryptography it uses; and a clear statement in a separate section of the design document of what security goals your protocol aims for.
2. Your code has another problem: it has a side channel leak that could be exploited to forge messages, because you're comparing secrets with `memcmp`.  In OpenSSL, you should use `CRYPTO_memcmp` instead.

Comment: Could you please give me some references so I can research about the memcmp side channel?

Comment: Just found this https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/11/preventing-timing-attacks-on-string-comparison-with-double-hmac-strategy thanks for the great answer

Comment: Maybe try searching the web for memcmp side channel?  Here are some of the first few hits: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/160808, https://rdist.root.org/2010/08/05/optimized-memcmp-leaks-useful-timing-differences/,  https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/11/preventing-timing-attacks-on-string-comparison-with-double-hmac-strategy, http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?memcmp+3+NetBSD-current  In OpenSSL, you should use `CRYPTO_memcmp`.